# How do I make a navigation app for android auto?

Tags: kotlin, android-auto, android-automotive

I understand that the question is too general but I really have no idea how to even start. So far only I've managed to build a Hello World app and that's it. Apparently, in order to develop an app in android auto you need to use one of their available templates, one of which is the navigation template. The problem is, I have no Idea how to implement it. Is there anybody out there who knows how this thing works because I've spent days trying to figure it out, and being a beginner in android development, this is a pain.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: I understand man.. but I've just lost all hope

Comment: Then start with something smaller that you can tackle.  Going from hello world to a navigation app is a pretty big leap.

Comment: It's a bit like learning a musical instrument. If someone came and said they've started learning guitar this week but I find it impossible to play impressive guitar solo riffs, all we could tell that person is that you need to start with the basics and put in the weeks of experience needed to build gradually on what you are capable of instead of jumping in the deep end.

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/navigation) start here